# Does my water heater require a drain pan and can I connect one to a condensate drain?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

Two part question...

The code says

> Where a storage tank-type water heater or a hot water storage tank is installed in a location where water leakage from the tank will cause damage...

There's two ways to read that.  One extreme view is that water will damage anything if left long enough and because there is no time bound in that clause, no place is actually an exception.  Another view is to assume a reasonable time frame and to exclude places where a water leak won't necessarily cause damage like a garage with a concrete floor that is sloped towards non-water tight garage door.

As it happens, my water heater just started leaking last night and my wife saw water pouring down the driveway before we turned the water off.  It didn't do any damage so would a replacement continue to not need a tub under the code?

My reluctance to putting in the tub is, of course, not the tub itself but the drain line.  As there's no tub now, there's also no drain line so I'd have to install one for the tub to be any value.

OR would I?

My A/C system is on the other side of the wall from the water heater, would it be allowed that I tap into the HVAC condensate line as it drains directly outside already?

The code says

> The pan shall be drained by an indirect waste pipe of not less than 3/4 inch (19 mm) diameter.

It doesn't say it needs to be dedicated although I could see that being implied by stating a diameter.

Comment: Where is your WH located?

Comment: in my garage with a concrete floor that is sloped towards the non-water tight garage door.

Comment: Is this a gas or an electric water heater? Is it in a small closet in the garage wall shared with the living quarters or is it exposed in the garage? Is the water heater elevated above the garage floor?

Comment: You should not tap into the condensate line, and your permitting authority would almost certainly not approve it. Since it already leaked without damage, you can conclude it is in a location where it can leak without damage. No pan needed, but I might put one anyway. You could put a water sensor and alarm in it.

Comment: It's gas, in a corner of the garage, not enclosed, on a block pedestal about 20 inches tall.

Comment: You will have to confirm with your permitting authority, but I'd say no pan would be required.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd prefer to have a pan except for the drain line.  The WH is not up against an exterior wall so running a drain line outside would be especially onerous.

Comment: Just put in a short line or even just a fitting that extends only a couple of inches.  This would direct any small to moderate leak where you want it to go.

Comment: That's exactly what I have; a pan under the heater and a short PVC fitting and piece of pipe that directs any leakage away from the sheet rock wall to the concrete floor. It passed inspection in my jurisdiction.